# SpringData paginação com PageImpl<> o size não funciona

Tags: paginação, spring-data, spring-jpa, spring-rest

Criei um método dentro de uma classe de serviço para gerar uma lista de produtos paginada utilizando SpringData (aplicação Java Spring Rest) , segue o código:

```
public Page<ProdutoDTOVendedor> listarProdutos(String descricao, Boolean disponivel,
            Integer page, Integer size, String orderBy, String direction) {

        //Rotina para validação do usuário do end-point
        UserSS us = AuthService.authenticated();

        Optional<Vendedor> vendedor = vendedorRepository.findById(us.getId());
        if (!vendedor.isPresent()) {
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Vendedor não encontrado");
        }

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Direction.valueOf(direction), orderBy);

        List<ProdutoDTOVendedor> produtosVendedor = new ArrayList<>();

        Optional<List<ItemVendedor>> itensVendedor = itemVendedorRepository.findByIdVendedorEqualsAndIdProdutoDescricaoDetalhadaContaining(vendedor.get(), descricao);
        for (ItemVendedor item : itensVendedor.get()) {
            produtosVendedor.add(itemVendedorToProdutoDTOVendedor(item));
        }
        Page<ProdutoDTOVendedor> produtosPage = new PageImpl<ProdutoDTOVendedor>(produtosVendedor,pageable,  (pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageSize()));      
        return produtosPage;
    }
```

O método gera a seguinte lista paginada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se vcs perceberem o atributo diz esta com o valor 24, por isso consegue trazer os 4 elementos da lista pois é o total que eu tenho cadastrado, porém se eu mudo este atributo size, a lista de itens deveria vir com a quantidade equivalente se o valor atribuído for menor do que eu tenho de produtos cadastrados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como podem ver coloquei na URI o parâmetro do size, o objeto pageable recebeu e reconheceu o parâmetro size corretamente, porém não surtiu efeito na lista de produtos, com o parâmetro no valor 1 deveria retornar somente 1 item e não a quantidade total. Acredito que não estou conseguindo trabalhar com o PageImpl<> da forma correta, como corrigir esta situação? Abaixo segue o código do método da classe resource responsável por chamar o método do serviço:

```
@GetMapping(value="/produtos/list")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<ProdutoDTOVendedor>> listarProdutos(

            @RequestParam(value = "descricao", defaultValue = "") String descricao,
            @RequestParam(value = "disponivel", defaultValue = "") Boolean disponivel,
            @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "24") Integer size,
            @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", defaultValue = "descricao") String orderBy,
            @RequestParam(value = "direction", defaultValue = "ASC") String direction) {
        Page<ProdutoDTOVendedor>  produtos = vendedorService.listarProdutos(descricao, disponivel, page, size, orderBy, direction);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(produtos);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para conseguir o resultado que precisava acabei alterando a abordagem da consulta, antes estava realizando a consulta criando uma instrução de palavras-chaves dentro do repository, porém quando convertia esta lista para outro formato não conseguia aproveitar o pageable, e nem implementar um pageable manualmente na nova lista criada, este era o problema.

Portanto, decidi criar a consulta do no próprio serviço utilizando EntityManager e JPQL, as querys criadas através desta abordagem que retornam listas suportam que vc trabalhe com paginação, para tal basta vc indicar o `setFirstResult` e o `setMaxResults` assim com esta informação sua lista poderá ser paginada. Vamos ao código referente a aplicação da consulta (simplifiquei a consulta para facilitar o entendimento), esta consulta ficou dentro do método de pesquisa do serviço:

```
String instrucao = "select prod from Produto prod order by descricaoDetalhada ";

Query jpql = em.createQuery(instrucao);

jpql.setFirstResult((page-1) * size); 
jpql.setMaxResults(size);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Produto> produtos = jpql.getResultList();
```

As variáveis page e size continuam vindo de dentro da assinatura do método:

```
public List<ProdutoDTOList> listarProdutosParaVincular(String descricao, Long categoriaID, Integer page, Integer size)
```

Tendo a lista de produtos que foi gerado pela getResultList() já paginada, então faço a conversão dela para que seus elementos tenham a estrutura do meu DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o problema esteja na consulta do banco de dados.
Como você esta montando o page acredito que o controle de registro deva ser seu, o spring não fara isso automático.

Faça um teste recebendo um elemento Pageable no metodo get e utilize findAll para ver se funciona

Ex

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<ProdutoDTOVendedor>> pesquisar(Pageable pageable) {
    // ...
    return itemVendedorRepository.findAll(pageable)
}
```

Funcionando tente passar o pageable no seu metodo de busca

`itemVendedorRepository.findByIdVendedorEqualsAndIdProdutoDescricaoDetalhadaContaining`

Caso não funcione acredito que tenhas que fazer o controle manualmente.

Comment: Fala Marcelo, tudo bem? Devido o tempo da pergunta, acabei alterando a abordagem de consulta para conseguir trabalhar com paginação neste cenário. Antes como havia descrito, esta utilizando uma abordagem através do método de palavras-chaves (Keywords) no repository, então alterei para uma abordagem utilizando o EntityManager e consulta JPQL no próprio serviço. Vou colocar na resposta do que fiz, mas de qualquer forma muito obrigado.